# ssis data conversion and null handling

Tags: ssis

Im pulling in data from an excel spreadsheet and using a data conversion component to convert the data to the relevant types.  Im testing this package and have noticed that the data conversion coomponent does not redirect a row if the value it is trying to convert is null.  Is this correct?  How can i handle nulls in this situation.  Should i check for nulls further up the stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Data Conversion Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141706.aspx) doesn't error out when the input data is null. Think of it much like as the tsql equivalent of `CAST(NULL AS char(10))` or data type. That conversion should always succeed, NULL can be any data type.

The error output for the transformation only handles two categories of conversion failure: error (incompatible type) and truncation.

If the desire is to not allow nulls in fields, I'd use conditional splits somewhere in your data flow to filter out those rows

Quick demo of NULL values not affecting Data Conversion Transformation

In an OLE DB source, I sent a row of nulls with varying data types out

```
SELECT
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS null_int
,   CAST(NULL AS varchar(10)) AS null_varchar
,   CAST(NULL AS nchar(5)) AS null_nchar
,   CAST(NULL AS decimal(5,4)) AS null_decimal
```

[image]

In the data conversion, I tried it with things that were safe (int to nvarchar) and things that were less so (nchar to to boolean)
[image]